# http authentication via htacces does not work on ubuntu

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, ubuntu

need a help with .htacces file to make http authentication.

I made .htacces and .htpasswd files due to tutorial on some web page, but it doesn't work.

.htacces file is very simple

AuthType Basic
AuthName "xxx"
AuthUserFile my/directory/path/
Require valid-user

Path is right, I checked it. Does anyone know what can be wrong please? Maybe there's something on ubuntu I should change or something.Thanks

Comment: Can you provide what you did and the outcome of it? The code and it's output when executing it please?

Comment: Sory, not sure that understand question. Simply in this directory are files for a web page, and I need to page asks for the password when entering it.

Comment: Ok so are you looking for command line to prompt for a password when accessing these folders?

Comment: I think that my .htacces file is ignored and I want to change it

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial your folllowing?

Comment: I used this generator http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/. I created .htacces  and .htpasswd files in this directory and copied the code which was given from generator.